How secure/fool-proof is Ubuntu's upgrade/update signature & certificate mechanism?
So instead of using just a handful of hubs that you can count on 1 hand for doing all the updates and upgrades, which would cause a plethora of problems, understandably Ubuntu pretty much gives every major country its own local "mirror"/CDN of some sort for updates & upgrades for that specific region and adjacent region.
Now, there's obviously a problem: this gives malicious 3rd parties like gov't agencies for example the perfect chance to temper with those update packages. Imagine you are unwittingly downloading a spyware.
Of course people who work on Ubuntu know about this potential risk so they will verify signatures and certificates whatnot during and update.
My question is, how reliable/secure is this whole system? Is it possible to be spoofed?

The repo packages index is signed.  To spoof it, you would either have to steal the private certificate piece or break the encryption in the certificate and duplicate it.  The first is a physical security issue (out of scope here), and the second is an encryption question (out of scope here).

In 25 years of Debian and 20 years of Ubuntu, there have been zero reported incidents of successful spoofing. It is possible to introduce malware onto an Ubuntu system --it's been done many times-- but other forms of attack are much easier.
